# control event propagation flex

Tags: apache-flex, events, controls, event-bubbling

Hello
I have a small issue:
There is an area containing multiple controls one on the other.
I want that the topmost control will not catch any events(or specifically mouse events).
Changing the z-index of the control is not good since I need it to stay the topmost control.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Define "Area"!  Do you mean a container?  Or just a portion of the screen?
Define "Top most control"!  Do you mean the parent of all these controls, refering to the display hierarchy?  OR do you refer to some visual aspect of the controls?

If you want to stop a component from broadcasing events, you can use [stopImmediatePropogation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#stopImmediatePropagation%28%29) in an event listener on the component.  Also check out docs for [stopPropogation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#stopPropagation%28%29) and read this documentation on the [three stages of where Flex events look for listeners](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_08.html).

Comment: @jeremy.mooer You're right I did use a lot of exclamation points there in the beginning.  It wasn't meant as yelling, though.